# Why physics simulation works in viewport but not in final render?

Tags: rendering, physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody, cache

I'm trying to render an animation 449 frames long. The animation part of the render is showing but the rigid body simulations are not visible. The simulation setting is set to 600 frames I tried deleting the cache multiple times and bake all dynamics again, I tried restarting blender, I double checked everything and I still cannot render the simulation ? Any other reasons the sim is not playing on final render ? I couldn't find an answer here so I'm posting the question. I think its a bug but might be something else ? Thanks

Comment: I tried messing with the world settings a bit more and now my whole simulation is not running at all even in the viewport... I deleted the Rigid Body World and then created new and selected Rigid Body World for my Collection and Rigid Body Constraints for the Constraints, since that's what was generated by Blender, then I delete all bakes then bake all dynamics and it doesnt work... I tried moving the objects with rigib bodies into a new collection altogether, which enabled the simulation on the viewport but everything just collapses and flies everywhere even if it's a passive rigid body

Comment: provide your blend file so we can help you